# SSRS - Struggling with Grouping

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I've got a table that looks like this...

[image: Table]

I need to create a report like this

[image: report]

but cant figure out how to create the columns in SSRS... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't going to be a simple achievement in SSRS, due to your grouped groups in the columns. You'll be better off part aggregating in SQL, and then doing the pivoting in SSRS.

Comment: The best way to ensure you have all the dates is to use a date table (tally table will work) as the driver for the report, that way you can join to it and then group by the month. Otherwise for months with no data no columns will be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight change to your data you can easily do this in SSRS.

Assuming your data is currently in a table that looks like example then you can use something like this in your dataset query..

```
SELECT Account, SalesPerson, Cost, Product, 'Expected' as Measure, ExpectedCloseDate as ActivityDate
    FROM myTable WHERE ExpectedCloseDate IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Account, SalesPerson, Cost, Product, 'Actual' as Measure, ActualCloseDate as ActivityDate
    FROM myTable WHERE ActualCloseDate IS NOT NULL
```

---

1. Then in your report, add a Matrix
2. Add a RowGroup that Groups by Account, SalesPerson and Product
3. Add a Column Group that groups by Measure
4. Add a Parent Column Group to the Measure column group that groups by
   Year and Month

Once this is done, drop the Cost field onto the matrix as the data field and that should be that other than a bit of formatting on the date.

If you are still struggling, let me know and I will post a full answer, I'm not at my PC at the moment (and it's midnight!)

Comment: This is what I love about SQL! There are so many ways to skin a cat! This is perfect and so simple! Thank you Alan!

Comment: Hi Alan, for some reason some columns are repeated, e.g. I am seeing 3 x 2020-04 columns, the first two both have Expected and Actual, and the third only Actual... why would this be, there is no spaces in the text anywhere

Comment: Ah... I originally formatted the Date field in the Parent Group. I removed that and did a Format(ActivityDate, 'MM-yyyy') as ActivityDate in the query instead and that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on SSRS reports, but the actual data pivoting can be done in SQL. The solution below uses [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)'s (CTE's) and the [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) keyword. The solution is not the most dynamic one, but it covers your example data.

```
-- create sample data
declare @data table
(
    Account nvarchar(15),
    SalesPerson nvarchar(15),
    Cost int,
    Product nvarchar(15),
    ExpectedCloseDate date,
    ActualCloseDate date
);

insert into @data (Account, SalesPerson, Cost, Product, ExpectedCloseDate, ActualCloseDate) values
('ABC House',   'John Doe',     120,    'Blocks',       '2020-02-03', '2020-02-03'),
('Pizza House', 'Jose Guava',   10,     'Boxes',        '2020-04-04', '2020-04-24'),
('The Hanger',  'John Doe',     10,     'Wings',        '2020-02-03', '2020-06-24'),
('The Store',   'John Doe',     10,     'Catnip',       '2020-02-03',  null       ),
('The Store',   'Jose Guava',   15,     'Boxes',        '2020-03-04', '2020-05-24'),
('WangTai',     'Pete Ringer',  20,     'Lettuce',      '2020-04-01', '2020-04-04'),
('WangTai',     'Pete Ringer',  22,     'Paper Plates', '2020-05-01',  null       ),
('Woolies',     'Pete Ringer',  20,     'Catnip',       '2020-03-04', '2020-03-04');
```

Solution overview:

1. Convert the dates to months.
2. Pivot the expected costs.
3. Pivot the actual costs.
4. Join everything together.

Solution:

```
-- solution 
with dataMonths as
(
    select  d.Account,
            d.SalesPerson,
            d.Product,
            d.Cost,
            month(d.ExpectedCloseDate) as 'ExpectedMonth',
            month(d.ActualCloseDate) as 'ActualMonth'
    from @data d
),
dataExpected as
(
    select  p.Account,
            p.SalesPerson,
            p.Product,
            [2] as 'ExpFeb20',
            [3] as 'ExpMar20',
            [4] as 'ExpApr20',
            [5] as 'ExpMay20',
            [6] as 'ExpJun20',
            [7] as 'ExpJul20'
    from dataMonths dm
    pivot ( sum(dm.Cost) for ExpectedMonth in ([2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]) ) p
),
dataActual as
(
    select  p.Account,
            p.SalesPerson,
            p.Product,
            [2] as 'ActFeb20',
            [3] as 'ActMar20',
            [4] as 'ActApr20',
            [5] as 'ActMay20',
            [6] as 'ActJun20',
            [7] as 'ActJul20'
    from dataMonths dm
    pivot ( sum(dm.Cost) for ActualMonth in ([2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]) ) p
)
select  dm.Account,
        dm.SalesPerson,
        dm.Product,
        de.ExpFeb20,
        da.ActFeb20,
        de.ExpMar20,
        da.ActMar20,
        de.ExpApr20,
        da.ActApr20,
        de.ExpMay20,
        da.ActMay20,
        de.ExpJun20,
        da.ActJun20,
        de.ExpJul20,
        da.ActJul20
from dataMonths dm
join dataExpected de
    on  de.Account = dm.Account
    and de.SalesPerson = dm.SalesPerson
    and de.Product = dm.Product
join dataActual da
    on  da.Account = dm.Account
    and da.SalesPerson = dm.SalesPerson
    and da.Product = dm.Product;
```

This gives me something quite close to the final report:

```
Account         SalesPerson     Product         ExpFeb20    ActFeb20    ExpMar20    ActMar20    ExpApr20    ActApr20    ExpMay20    ActMay20    ExpJun20    ActJun20    ExpJul20    ActJul20
--------------- --------------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
ABC House       John Doe        Blocks          120         120         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Pizza House     Jose Guava      Boxes           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10          10          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
The Hanger      John Doe        Wings           10          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        10          NULL        NULL
The Store       John Doe        Catnip          10          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
The Store       Jose Guava      Boxes           NULL        NULL        15          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        15          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
WangTai         Pete Ringer     Lettuce         NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        20          20          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
WangTai         Pete Ringer     Paper Plates    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        22          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Woolies         Pete Ringer     Catnip          NULL        NULL        20          20          NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, and if I dont succeed with the other suggestion, this will be what I will use. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer in such detail.